# How can I aggregate values inside a jsonb array using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

My data looks something like this:

```
                    tags                      |                 fullName
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 ["tag1", "tag2"]                             | John
 ["tag3", "tag1"]                             | Jane
 ["tag1", "tag3"]                             | Bob
```

tags is a `jsonb` type and fullName a `text` in a postgres database

What I'm struggling to do is, create a view such as

```
                    tags                      |                 count
----------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 tag1                                         | 3
 tag2                                         | 1
 tag3                                         | 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function to expand the row as array elements before grouping and counting.

See example and working fiddle below.

```sql
    SELECT
        tag_names as tag,
        COUNT(1) as count
    FROM (
        SELECT
            jsonb_array_elements(tags) as tag_names
        FROM
            my_table
    ) t
    GROUP BY tag_names;
```

| tag | count |
| --- | --- |
| tag1 | 3 |
| tag2 | 1 |
| tag3 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwYsgmr5S6rXVvLbGNscgP/0)

Or shorter

```sql
SELECT
   jsonb_array_elements(tags) as tag,
   COUNT(1) as count
FROM
   my_table
GROUP BY 
   tag
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwYsgmr5S6rXVvLbGNscgP/1)